# Can I view and edit Google Calendar events in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am able to create Google calendar events from a Google sheet. I want to know if I can  **view** and **edit** Google calendar events in a Google sheet.

I have read the following, but I am unsure if it will do what I want...

"Allows a script to read and update the user's Google Calendar. This class provides direct access to the user's default calendar, as well as the [ability to retrieve additional calendars that the user owns or is subscribed to](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)).

Comment: To view, edit, update calendar event, you will need the eventID. Then refer to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

Comment: Share your present spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks. I will read up on eventID. Also, I have not created a spreadsheet yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. Query the calander to get the events (with the event id)
2. Write to the sheet
3. Have some logic in the sheet, like a dropdown with status (update/delete/untouched/create)
4. Do your thing in the sheet and then call the function
5. Based on the dropdown status call functions ti handle the logic that comes with the status.
6. Reset the dropdown in the sheet / delete the row?

That would be the high over logic.

Comment: Thank you! I like to use the following view in Google Calendar...
https://imgur.com/vXVGZwB It works pretty well for me, but I would like to improve it. The fonts are too small for me to read comfortably. And no, pressing ctrl++  to increase the font sizes doesn't solve my problem. Also, the top and left margin in the screnshot have a lot of wasted space.